# Deserialize List to Specific Property

Tags: java, json, jackson

I've got a simple issue that is now taking me way to long to figure out.

I want to deserialize this:

```
[
   { "a": "a", "b": 1 }
   { "a": "b", "b": 2 }
]
```

Into this:

```
@Data
public class MyObject {
    private List<BaseType> rootList;
}
```

The reason I want to do this is because I was previously just extending ArrayList but now I actually need a real class that it needs to inherit from so I can't do that anymore. I basically just need Jackson to populate that inner property instead of me having to wrap the class.

Is there an annotation that does this?

Thank you!

Comment: add BaseType class code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i got your question right, you want to deserialize json array into object with array field, containing all the json array items. One thing you could do is create custom constructor and annotate it with `@JsonCreator`. For serialization you could use `@JsonValue`  above your `rootList` List field.

```
private static String json = "[{\"a\":\"a\",\"b\":1},{\"a\":\"b\",\"b\":2}]";
@Data
public static class MyObject {
    @JsonValue   // used during serialization
    private List<BaseType> rootList;
    @JsonCreator //used during deserialization
    public MyObject(List<BaseType> items ) {
        this.rootList = items;
    }
}

@Data
public static class BaseType {
    @JsonProperty
    private String a;
    @JsonProperty
    private int b;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    MyObject value = mapper.readValue(json, MyObject.class);
    System.out.println(value);
    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(value));
}
```

Comment: Is there no other way to do it other than create a new constructor with @JsonCreator ? This is a pretty good solution though, it's basically exactly what I wanted, have you tested it to make sure it will deserialize right? I'm about to test it right now.

Comment: Since this answer was kind of delayed, I ended up making a custom deserializer that deserializes a root list like this onto the field with a custom annotation. And then I made a custom annotation with @JacksonInside with @JsonDeserializer(using=MyCustomDeserializer.class) ... Although I like a solution with native jackson annotations so I don't have to worry about edge cases in the Deserializer.

Comment: @A.Bello was away for some time, so sorry for delay. Yeah it should work just like you'd expect it to. `@JsonDeserializer` is also nice option especially if you cant change POJO code in any way, like when POJO is part of 3-d party library, you still can use `@JsonDeserializer` with mixin, but cant use this approach. And yes, you need to have @JsonCreator above custom constructor or 2-nd option is to use static factory function. [Here is more info](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_457.html)